# Multiple alarms with AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I am building a water reminder app on Android and would like to schedule a limited amount of alarms every day that STOP after a specific time (set by the user) and restart on the next day without the user having to open the app. How do I go about it?

I can't see how I can set repeating alarms because I want them to STOP at one point and restart the next day, and repeating alarms don't do that. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set tow alarms the first is a repeating alarm used for the reminder.
The other alarm is used to stop the first alarm at the specific time and then schedule alarms for the next day.

Comment: But how do you set it for more days without the user having to open the app?

Comment: when you receive the last alarm of this day you set the alarms of the next day. the receiver works when it receives the alarm and without opining the app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample code. This may help you, but I am not sure.

MainActivity:

```
public static int NOW_NOTIFICATION = 101; 

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationReceiver.class);
                intent.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE, "Sample Alert");
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        MainActivity.this, NOW_NOTIFICATION, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

                cancelNotification(NOW_NOTIFICATION);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                        + (2 * 1000), pendingIntent);
```

Cancel Notification:

```
public void cancelNotification(int requestCode) {
        try {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), requestCode, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

NotificationReceiver:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static String NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE = "notificationMessage";


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        //Define sound URI
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, EmptyActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        final DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
        int color = 0xffffaa00;
//        int color1 = context.getColor(R.color.notificatinBackgroundColor);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.festi_push_message_small);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setContentTitle("Notification Sample");
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setContentText(message + ", Current Time : " + dateTime.getHourOfDay() + ":" + dateTime.getMinuteOfHour() + ":" + dateTime.getSecondOfMinute());
        builder.setSound(soundUri);
        builder.setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 1000);
        builder.setColor(color);


        Notification notification = builder.build();

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(102938, notification);
    }

}
```

DateChangedReceiver:

```
public class DateChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static String NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE = "notificationMessage";

    public static int NOW_NOTIFICATION = 101;

    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;
        Intent intentNitification = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
        intentNitification.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE, "Sample Alert");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, NOW_NOTIFICATION, intentNitification, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        cancelNotification(NOW_NOTIFICATION);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                + (2 * 1000), pendingIntent);
    }

    public void cancelNotification(int requestCode) {
        try {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifiest:

```
<receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver" />

        <receiver android:name=".DateChangedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```